# zsh while loop exiting prematurely in a triple nested loop using floating point arithmetic

Tags: shell, floating-point, zsh

I have a zsh script that should generate a bunch of Z-matrix files, but it exits the while loops after one iteration. N and M never increase

```
#!/bin/zsh
n=0.5 
m=0.5
a=60.0
i=1

while [[ $n -le 1.5 ]];do
    while [[ $m -le 1.5 ]];do
        while [[ $a -le 160 ]];do
            echo $i
            echo "o" > H2O.$i.Z
            eval echo "h  1" $n >> H2O.$i.Z
            eval echo "h  1" $m "2" $a >> H2O.$i.Z

            let i=$i+1
            let a=$a+5.0
        done
        let m=$m+0.05
    done
    let n=$n+0.05
done
```

I'm new to zsh; is my syntax wrong?

Comment: If your syntax was wrong, it wouldn't get as far as iterating once.  The `eval` operations are curious; about the only thing they do, by my (Bourne shell conditioned) reckoning is remove the extra space between the `h` and the `1` in the echoed material.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-le` operator operates on integers. For floating point, use the built-in arithmetic.
I also believe you might actually want to re-initialize the values for `m` and `a` in the inner loops. Then the bug is that you only initialized them once at the beginning and the inner loop conditions on the second iteration were false.

You might use a `for((;;))` loop to write this more compact:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh
i=1
for ((n=0.5; n <= 1.5; n+=0.05)); do
  for ((m=0.5; m <= 1.5; m+=0.05)); do
    for ((a=60.0; a <= 160; a+=5.0)); do
      echo $i $a $m $n
      let i=$i+1
    done
  done
done
```

Note also that it is **unwise to use floating point numbers as loop counts**. Did you know that ten times 0.1 is hardly ever one? This might explain why you lose or gain an extra iteration.
Instead, you should iterate using an integer number N and compute the required floats as 0.5 + N * 0.05, for example.

Comment: @DominiqueNocito You're welcome. The next step would be to *accept* an answer you deem acceptable by clicking the "check" sign to the left. This will earn you another two points.

Answer (score 1):

The `-le` operator only supports integer comparisons. For floating-point, you need to use the `((...))` command. Also, you don't need `eval`, and you can combine the three echos into one command so you only have to redirect once.

```
while (( n < 1.5 )); do
  while (( m < 1.5 )); do
    while (( a <= 160 )); do
      echo $i
      { echo "o"; echo "h  1" $n; echo "h   1" $m "2" $a; } > H20.$i.Z
      ((i+=1))
      ((a+=5.0))
    done
    ((m+=0.05))
  done
  ((n+=0.5))
done
```

Comment: Thanks it made my script cleaner, but didn't solve my problem with m, and n not increasing by 0.05. It just goes one cycle through the while (( n < 1.5 )); and while (( m < 1.5 )); loops when they are 0.5 instead of increasing 0.55,0.6,0.65..

Comment: @chepner Another problem might be that `a` and `m` were never reset on the next iteration, like is usually done with nested loops.

Comment: Good point. I got as far as checking if the C-style for loop can do floating-point arithmetic (it can't), but didn't consider the structure of the while loop further.